# How to <include> element from another module with Databinding? - Android

Tags: android, layout, data-binding, include

I have two modules, *common* and *application1*.

*common* includes `toolbar.xml`, (which contains a Button) and *application1* includes `MainActivity` and `activity_main`.

In `activity_main.xml`, I want to include the toolbar which I declared in *common*. However, when I try to access the Button in the toolbar from `MainActivity`, I get an error

> Cannot access 'com.application1.databinding.ToolbarBinding'. Check
> module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies

Does anyone know how to fix this? I've implemented the 'common' in gradle, but it still doesn't work. Below is my setup:

#### application1.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':common')
}
```

#### common/res/layout/toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

#### application1/res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
        android:text="Some Random Text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### application1/java/MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var mBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        mBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        mBinding.toolbar.button.setEnabled(true) // Cannot access 'databinding.ToolbarBinding'
        setContentView(mBinding.root)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show toolbar layout?

Comment: you can access mBinding.toolbar.button.setEnabled(true)

Comment: I can't access mBinding.toolbar.button because it's not in the same module. That's the whole reason why I made this post

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: not yet.this is actually really important so i might place a bounty on it

Comment: I will give you answer within 30 minutes

Comment: Great! I appreciate your time. The key here is that mBinding.toolbar.button is in a difference directory. If I put it in the application1 directory, then I have access, but it has to stay in common with the way our code is set up

Comment: Oh different modules. I thought it's in a single module. Yesterday the question was not like I think. I need to research this. sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217605/discussion-between-el-sushiboi-and-shalu-t-d).

Comment: you have declared mBinding as of type ActivityPackageScanBinding I guess it's a typo confirm it and edit your question as well

Comment: Yes it was a typo, which I have fixed. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: And one more doubt is it a compile-time error or runtime error?

Comment: Compile-time. `mBinding.toolbar` is not visible

Answer (score 1):

> How to access `include` element from another `module` with `Databinding`?

**We need to do the below points for getting a layout and binding from another module:**

1. The module should be an `Android Library module`
2. This lib module should be mentioned in the app Gradle file inside dependency as

   ```
   dependencies {
         api project(':mylibrary')
     }
   ```
3. Both the app module and library module gradle file should mention the databinding as,

   ```
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
   ```

**Then in your both xml, do put the  tag for binding the layout. So both
the xml will be as below:**

1. The library module XML:

   ```
    <layout>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </layout>
   ```
2. The app module XML:

   ```
     <layout>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

          <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                 
            android:text="Some Random Text" />

       </LinearLayout>
    </layout>
   ```

**Then, in your activity you can simply access the button inside the library as below:**

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val binding: ActivityMainBinding =
            DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
        binding.toolbar.button // you can access now
    }
```

Comment: I've done everything in your answer - My module is already a Android Library, I've already added common as a dependency, I've enabled databinding on both modules, and put tags on relevant elements, but it still doesn't work for me :(

Comment: I don't thinkg it's a good idea to have the included layout have id `toolbar` and the root of the included layout have the same id `toolbar`. At best it makes debugging harder, and it may be the reason it gets confused.

Answer (score 1):

Many times databinding goes crazy on my laptop and caches old code. I have this going on for maybe a year, on many kotlin, android studio and gradle versions. When it happens I usually do one or all of the following:

`./gradlew clean assembleDebug`
`./gradlew clean assembleDebug --no-build-cache`

After the command line compiles fine Android Studio is back working.

Maybe not specific to your problem, when those don't do the job I do `./gradlew assembleDebug --stacktrace` and carefully read the errors from bottom to top.

Of course, you also have to wrap both layout files with `<layout>` and have databinding enabled in both layouts.

If you want to access the View objects instead of doing databinding, I'd recommend taking a look at https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding which is a recent implementation and probably better quality than databinding, which is quite hard to work with when any error comes out of it.